# Code first node tree implementation with many parents nodes

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I'm trying to implement tree view using code first to save it in db. Entity class is

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to use the class, it looks like EF saves a *Child*, not a *Parent*.

For example, I've created a parent node *'Category1'* and then a child node *'Category2'* (and added *'Category1'* to Parents collection)

```
entity.Parents.Add(new Category(){...});
```

But instead of the expected behavior *"Category2_child_for_Category1"*, I see *"Category1_child_for_Category2"*

[image]

And if I try to save a couple of parents, db saves only the last value from the list as a child, not a parent.

Can anybody explain how to fix it?

Many thanks

Comment: Tree node with many parents? I don't think this is gonna work. Any reason of not usng the normal design with single optional 0..1 parent and 0..N children?

Comment: Ivan, many thanks for your answer. The reason for creating such behavior is when a user add a new node, he knows parents, not childs. But I think it is not a big deal. I'm surprised, that it doesn't work in EF ))

Comment: @Egor If each node can have multiple parents, rather than just one, then you don't have a tree anymore, you just have a directed graph.

Comment: Servy, thank you for your answer. Looks like need a re-design of logic.